# Second battery in UTV for stereo only

Tags: automotive, stereo

I am adding a second battery to a UTV just for the stereo. It is placed right next to the stock battery. I want the aux, stereo, battery to charge while running but when the IGN is off to be isolated. This is so I can run the stereo battery down and still be able to start the UTV with a strong stock battery. I think the stock battery is charged somewhere before the battery connection so I can't isolate the charging wire from the stock battery easily. I bought a 10 sec delay timer to activate a 80A stinger relay to connect both batteries once the IGN is on and running. I also bought some 20A diodes but I can only put these diodes inline to the aux battery, 4 in parallel.

Does anyone see anything wrong with this? I think it will charge the stock battery to .7V higher than the aux battery if I am correct.

Comment: I think you need to add a rough schematic to improve responses

Comment: What's a UTV? It's a good idea to explain TLAs (three-letter acronyms) when first used.

Comment: Also, what's an "IGN" and "stinger relay?" This question does not make sense.

Comment: Looks like "UTV" is a "utility terrain vehicle," "IGN" is shorthand for "ignition," and a "stinger relay" is a type of high-current relay from a _company_ called Stinger Electronics. @teknotek for future reference please understand your audience when writing questions -- electrical terms are expected here, but automotive/audio-specific ones may not be known.

Comment: @teknotek do you mind if I delete this question?

Answer (score -1):

I ended up buying a battery isolator, instead of kinda making my own.